# Get id from URL in Cloud Functions for Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

If I got this line of code:

```
functions.database.ref('/users/{randomid}/{uid}')
```

I can get the key from uid by event.data.key;, but how can I get the id from randomid? randomkey is generated by childByAutoId in Swift. Thanks.

Comment: It's described in the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the key generated for `{randomid}` use:

```
const randomid= event.params.randomid;
```